# Push the value to input array field

Tags: javascript, php

How can I add elements to input with name as array?

```
<input type="hidden" class="deleted-images" name="deletedImages[]" value="">
```

```
const deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.delete-resource');
const removedImagesInput = document.querySelector('.deleted-images');

deleteButtons.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function () {
       item.closest('.input-photo-preview').style.display = 'none';
       removedImagesInput.value += parseInt(item.getAttribute('data-image-id')) + ',';

    });
})
```

At the output in PHP I want to get an array:

```
deletedImages => [1,2,...n]
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is...what is the result you are currently getting?

Comment: You would need to add a separate `name="deletedImages[]"` input for each image id. Your best option is to just [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) your comma separated list of image ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for PHP to receive an array, you'd need multiple elements with `name="deletedImages[]"`.
For example, you can clone your existing `.deletedImages` element for each new value:

```js
const deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.delete-resource');
const removedImagesInput = document.querySelector('.deleted-images');
const removedImagesInputParent = removedImagesInput.parentNode;
//prevent submitting empty value
removedImagesInputParent.removeChild(removedImagesInput);

deleteButtons.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function () {
       item.closest('.input-photo-preview').style.display = 'none';
       //create new <input> element
       const elInput = removedImagesInput.cloneNode(false);
       elInput.value = item.getAttribute('data-image-id');
       //insert new <input> into DOM
       removedImagesInputParent.appendChild(elInput);
    });
})
```

Otherwise, you'd need send JSON or comma separated text (as your attempt does) and in php decode it into an array with something like:

```php
$deletedImages = explode(",", $_POST['deletedImages']);
```